# .htaccess mod_rewrite subdirectories with file extension condition

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite link from 
         `domain.com/user/upload/12345.jpg` to `domain.com/12345.jpg`, but only when file extension is `jpg`,`gif` or `png`.
I think, it should be like this:

```
     RewriteRule ^user/upload/$ /$1 [L, QSA]
```

But my version do not work. How can i fix it?

Comment: According to your rule, it seems you want to map this: `domain.com/12345.jpg` to this: `domain.com/user/upload/12345.jpg` and not the other way around as you say in the question. Would make sense as the shorter and "pretty" URI is the incoming one, the first one.

Comment: You are right, I want to map this `domain.com/12345.jpg` to this: `domain.com/user/upload/12345.jpg. Maybe I`ve not quite correctly explained this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /([^/]+)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$
RewriteRule .* http://domain.com/user/upload/%1.%2 [L]
```

Will map this:

`http://domain.com/any_name.any_extension`

To this:

`http://domain.com/user/upload/any_name.any_extension`

**OPTION**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  (/m)?/([^/]+)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$
RewriteRule .* http://domain.com/user/upload%1/%2.%3
```

Will map this:

`http://domain.com/any_name.any_extension` or this

`http://domain.com/m/any_name.any_extension`

To this:

`http://domain.com/user/upload/any_name.any_extension` or this

`http://domain.com/user/upload/m/any_name.any_extension`

depending on the presence of `/m` sub-directory.

Comment: With this rule I have cyclic(or cyclical? - my english is bad, sorry) forwarding.

Comment: Error 310 (net :: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.

Comment: Now it works! Thank you, I've spend all my last evening to solve this problem, and you solved it so fast) And what if I want to rewrite also this url:
`http://domain.com/m/any_name.any_extension` to `http://domain.com/user/upload/m/any_name.any_extension`?

Comment: OK. The last part of the comment was missing. ¿Is `/m` a fixed folder name or it can be any name?

Comment: `http://domain.com/m/any_name.any_extension` is incoming, and `http://domain.com/user/upload/m/any_name.any_extension` is mapped (I have '/m' directory in '/upload'). In other words I want to transform `http://domain.com/m/any_name.any_extension` into  `http://domain.com/user/upload/m/any_name.any_extension`.

Comment: No, you do not quite understand me correctly. I need to rewrite 2 types of link: 
1) `http://domain.com/any_name.any_extension` -> `http://domain.com/user/upload/any_name.any_extension`
2) `http://domain.com/m/any_name.any_extension` -> `http://domain.com/user/upload/m/any_name.any_extension`
So, I want to user get thumbnail of image with `domain.com/m/12345.png`, and full version of image with `domain.com/12345.png`. And on server thumbnails are in `user/upload/m/...` dir, and fullsized images are in `user/upload/`.

Comment: So you want a single rule for both possibilities. I will modify the option.

Comment: Updated. Hope that's what you need.

Comment: And again Error 310 (net :: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.

Comment: My mistake. I commented 2 conditions.  Will fix them right now.

Comment: Yes, now in works clear) Thank you for your help, your tips were very useful) Can you advise some manual or book to improve my .htaccess skills?

Comment: You are welcome. If you are satisfied with the answer, you might consider [**accepting**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) it.
Just go to Apache site. There you can find a complete documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your real path is user/upload and you want it to be like in the root dir (makes sense to me). Otherwise, just change paths.

I think this would do the trick.

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\.(jpg|gif|png)$ http://domain.com/user/upload/$1.$2 [NC,L]
```

or, also this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.(jpg|gif|png)$ http://domain.com/user/upload/$1.$2 [NC,L]
```

You have no query string, to pass QSA (for example: `?id=5&name=myname`, after the ? is the query string).

**EDIT:**

In case you want to preserve the rewrite url for remote redirects better redirect all matches to local file like: remoteimage.php:

RewriteRule ^(.+?).(jpg|gif|png)$ remoteimage.php?filename=$1&extension=$2 [NC,L]

This file will read the image and would resend it to the browser...

Something like:

```
<?php
    // Remote image
    $filename = $_GET['filename'];
    $ext = $_GET['extension']; // Of course you will need some validations, etc.


    header('Content-type: image/' . ($ext != 'jpg' ? $ext : 'jpeg'));

    // This is the idea, you could use cURL, fopen, etc. and you probably need to validate response status code and received data
    $image = file_get_contens("http://domain.com/user/upload/{$filename}.{$extension}");

    echo $image;
?>
```

If you use some frameworks like codeigniter, kohana, etc., you might need to try catch the reading.

Comment: I`ve tried both rules, but they caused the 500 error, but with first rule rewrites link into `Z:/home/localhost/www/user/upload/256.jpeg` on local server.
And correct path to file is Z:/home/localhost/www/photohosting/user/upload/256.jpeg

Comment: Ok, these are system paths. Are they separate vhosts, or directories, in the same host? Its good to post this information with the question, in order receive more accurate answers.

Comment: On my localhost they are directories in the same host. On the remoted web-server this is a subdomain, and I dont know all file structure (I`m not administrator). But two subdomains organized like this: `subdomain1/public_html/..` and '`subdomain2/public_html/..`'.

Comment: See the edited post, if you need remote rewrite you should enter the whole URL.

However, when you rewrite outside the host, it will be a redirect, and will not stay in the url. See the edited answer for some suggestions.

Comment: Now url is correct, but I have Error 310 (net :: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.

Comment: Are these URL redirects points back to the place where we have started it, or there are some other redirects inside the domain.com .htaccess? It seems to me there are other redirects on the remote domain.

Comment: These URL redirects points back to the place where we have started it. But problem now solved with @Felipe Alameda A-s tips above , thanks for your help)